# Image processing loop using EBImage in R

Tags: r, loops, image-processing

```
require("EBImage")
```

I essentially want to loop this set of commands in R for generating masks of images

```
a <- readImage('BF_Position004_time021.tif') # load rgb image
g <- channel(a, "asgreen") #take green channel from image 
writeImage(g,"/Users/...path.../GFP_Position004_time021.tif") #save green channel image
r <- channel(a, "asred") #take red channel from image
writeImage(r,"/Users/...path.../RFP_Position004_time021.tif")#save red
b <- channel(r, "gray") #makes red channel into gray scale
#the following creates a white mask over pixels with high intensity
nmask2 = thresh(sqrt(b), 15, 15, .001)
# nmask2 = fillHull(nmask2)
mk3 = makeBrush(3, shape = 'diamond')
nmask3 = opening(nmask2, mk3)
nseg = bwlabel(nmask3)
nf = computeFeatures.shape(nseg)
nr = which(nf[,'s.area'] < 150)
nseg = rmObjects(nseg,nr) #resulting image called nseg
writeImage(nseg,"/Users/...path.../BF_Position004_time021.tif") #save nseg with the following name
```

I want to do across multiple positions from 000 to 100 and for time points 001 to 100. I have annotated the above code for some clarity

thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the commands above into a function that takes the common part of the file name and the directory where you'd like to write to

```
fun <- function(fl, dirpath) {
    a <- readImage(sprintf("BF_%s", fl))
    ...
    writeImage(g, file.path(dirpath, sprintf("GFP_%s", fl)))
    ....
}
```

Create a vector of file names

```
fls <- sprintf("Position%03d_time%03d.tif", rep(0:100, each=100), 1:100)
```

and go!

```
for (fl in fls)
    fun(fl, "/Users/...path...")
```